How do I set my apt mirror in crunchbang++ 12?
So, basically, I was installing crunchbang++ (or #!++) and my WiFi drivers weren't set up (it said it needed r34/ucode.fw and r34-open/ucode.fw), so I decided to skip setting up network and apt mirrors, eventually I completed the install and used USB tethering with a tablet to get internet, and now I need to figure out how to set an apt mirror (or would it do this automatically?). once I get apt set up I will fix the WiFi driver stuff
